# Embedded SWF: Finding the framerate of the child SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

I have a program that dynamically loads SWFs a user has uploaded to a server into another, larger, SWF. This means the embedded SWF can be any framerate and I have no control or knowledge of what is being uploaded.

What I want to do is show a message to the user that the framerate does not match the parent SWFs framerate and that it might playback too quickly or slowly.

However, when I try to find the framerate (using swfLoader.loaderInfo.frameRate) it only displays the parent's framerate, because the child's has been changed.

I need a way to find the framerate the original child SWF was set to before it was changed by the parent.

I tried going to Google for this issue, but nothing turned up a working solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `contentLoaderInfo.frameRate` instead.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be working with SWFLoader.  


My loader is 
<mx:SWFLoader id="swfLoader" width="100%" height="100%" source="{_source}" loaderContext="{_loaderContext}" maintainAspectRatio="false" complete="loadComplete(event)"/>

Comment: You have not mentioned you are using Flex. In that case you should do swfLoader.content.loaderInfo.frameRate. That should do it.